# C++ Variadic Delegates

Tags: c++, templates, delegates, function-pointers, variadic-templates

I am trying to make a Variadic Delegate structure while trying to grasp templates and variadic template arguments. I came up with the following:

```
    template <typename T, typename R, typename... Parameters>
    class Delegate
    {
    private:
        T& object;
        R (T::*method)(Parameters...);

    public:
        Delegate(T& object, R(T::*method)(Parameters...))
            : object(object), method(method)
        {}

        R Call(Parameters...)
        {
            return (object.*method)(Parameters...);
        }
    };
```

and my main function looks like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    int F(int a)
    {
        return a * x;
    }

    int x;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.x = 5;

    Delegate<A, int, int> d(a, &A::F);
    d.Call(8);
    return 0;
}
```

But that gives me the following errors:

```
error C2144: syntax error : 'int' should be preceded by ')'
while compiling class template member function 'int Swift::Utility::Delegate<A,int,int>::Call(int)'

error C2198: 'int (__thiscall A::* )(int)' : too few arguments for call

error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

I tried some different ways on calling the member functions but I can't get it to work...

Also if you can show me a different alternative that provides the same basic functionality I would also be happy!

Comment: Use std::function, maybe in conjunction with a lambda

Comment: Could you provide me a reason why that would be better? Thanks for helping though!

Comment: Note that support for variadic templates in Microsoft C++ requires a very new version of the compiler.  You might yet run into some cases where the code is ok but the compiler isn't finished yet.

Comment: Thanks for warning me! I am using VS2013 though, so I should be safe. But I will keep it in mind when trying to make it crossplatform:P

Comment: @DieterLücking I searched it up and I understand what you mean! Thanks:P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not providing actual arguments, only their types:

```
R Call(Parameters... params)
{
    return (object.*method)(params...);
}
```

is probably what you were looking for (or close to it).

Comment: You're my hero! I guess it shouldn't be Parameter&& because the reference is already provided when specifying the template? I was wondering too!: Since I am trying to learn variadic templates and delegates, what do you think of my code? Is it bad? Thanks for helping out a noob like me!

Comment: @ChristianVeenman sorry about the pf-refs. I'm much more frequent to do this with variadic params at the member level; not the class. Interesting clang didn't yelp about it. Anyway, glad it helped. That you understand member-function pointer vernacular and variadic template arguments at all puts you miles head of most beginning C++ programmers, so I think you're doing fine. keep plunging ahead, and best of luck.

Comment: I have been programming C++ for a few years but templates have always been magic to me. Thanks a lot again! Consider it done!